# Why does github have a pull request number?

Tags: git, github

Why is there a number associated with a pull request? Is it a shortcut to some commit hash? I know we use this PR to deploy things, but I am trying to understand what's going on behind the scenes.

Comment: Pull-requests are not native to `git`. They are abstractions built specifically for and offered by GitHub. (Other competing services like BitBucket also have their own pull request systems.)

Comment: An alternative is to use `git` patches directly. (e.g. This is what Torvalds prefers for the `linux` and `git` projects.) See also: [Why do some open source projects do not accept pull requests, but emailing patch files only](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/149199/why-do-some-open-source-projects-do-not-accept-pull-requests-but-emailing-patch)

Answer (score 0):

The pull request number can be used to refer/reply to the initial pull request, it's just one of the helpful features Github has.

Comment: In other words, it's just an incrementing counter, and not related to any git ids

Answer (score 0):

Pull requests are not something in Git in the first place: they're an add-on.

Each hosting provider that uses Git—the Big Three today seem to be GitHub, Bitbucket, and GitLab—has their own method of providing something that is almost always called a *pull request*.  The precise details vary from one provider to another, so to get a complete answer, you must specify a particular provider.

GitHub's "thing" or "value-add" (or whatever term you want to use here to describe their *raison d'être*) is to allow social networking.<sup>1</sup>  As such, they let anyone—or almost anyone, depending on privacy settings, and note that some abilities require payment—access *your* repository and create "issues" and "pull requests" and other such things.  In GitHub's case, these are all sequentially numbered.  That's all the pull-request number is: a sequential number, the next number available at the time someone clicked on the "new issue" or "new pull request" or whatever button.  It is not related to Git hash IDs.

---

<sup>1</sup>The idea here is that the value of a site like GitHub increases when more people use it: the [*Network Effect*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_effect).

Comment: I never mentioned in my question that it's git specific. Also, I mentioned the provider I want to hear it for - Github, so the first part of your answer (first 2 paragraphs) does not answer to the question and perhaps could be removed.

Comment: It's strange it does not carry any value besides the sequential number. We use this number when deploying things, that's why I was asking if it has any relation to some commits.

Comment: No, but you tagged this both `git` *and* `github`, and for many people, that means "applicable to either any use of Git, or any use of GitHub". Your question itself does not specifically restrict this to GitHub. So it's important to note that the answer is GitHub-specific. If your question were only tagged "GitHub", or your question were specific to GitHub, the first two paragraphs would be redundant.